# WCF - Inspect an MTOM encoded message BeforeSendRequest

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, mtom

I'm integrating with a third party WCF service that is using Mtom as the message encoding.
I have created a message inspector behavior, and i'm able to view the message request "string" by calling `request.ToString()`, However, the message never appears to be mtom encoded, and doesn't include any MIME parts. I'm assuming the Mtom encoding happens later in the channel pipeline. My question is, is there a way to view the actual outgoing message regardless of encoding as it will be sent over the wire to the WCF service?

Below is the message inspector i'm using:

```
public class InspectorBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public InspectorBehaviorExtensionElement()
    {

    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(InspectorBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new InspectorBehavior();
    }

}

public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}

public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public MessageInspector()
    {

    }
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Received the following reply: '{0}'", reply);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Sending the following request: '{0}'", request);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK message encoding is applied after `BeforeSendRequest`. You may use WCF Message logging or fiddler to see the messages.